# Can You Use 2 Python Modules Issued Under LGPL and BSD License in a Program?

Tags: licensing, python, gpl, bsd-license

I'm making a drawing program as my first open-source program merely to get a taste of the open-source community. To make said program, I am using Python 2.7. I'm using the following modules:

1. EasyGUI 0.96 - Under the 3-clause BSD license
2. Pygame 1.9.1 - Under the LGPL 2.1 license

All I intend to do is create a program using these modules which depend on it, and upload it to a public GitHub repository for others to freely modify and distribute.  *If* using my code is allowed in closed source software, or profits to be made by others, I do not want it.  I do not wish to modify Pygame or EasyGUI themselves, either.  They just need to be simply provided to run the software.

Is this possible with the two licenses mentioned above? If I were to do this, what license would I have to issue my program under and why? Are some better choices than others?

Is it also possible release my drawing program code under a reciprocal license so the people contributing send their bug fixes in my script back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither license limits what *other* libraries you can use in your project, nor do they dictate what license the overall program (the "Application" in the LGPL license) should use.

You are free to release your program under whatever license you choose. All you have to do is list both projects and their licenses in your application documentation (see "4. Combined Works" in the LGPL license for the more detailed rules that license requires of you).

If you want to force people to share any modifications to your application they make, use the GPL license (note, no `L` at the start) for that program.